# OutofMemory Exception Dropdownlist when autopostback=true

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a master page than contains my ScriptManager.
On a child page i have an updated panel.
Inside the update panel there is a dropdowlist.
When i set the autopostback=true i get OutofMemory Exceptions.
All the time.
Please also note that I have AjaxControlToolkit set on my web.config.

Here is parts of my Code.

MasterPage.aspx

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Child Page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upChTime" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <tr>
                <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txChTimeClientCode" /></td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dpChTimeClient" /></td>
           </tr>
```

So when i set the AutoPostBack=True on the DropdownList the Visual Studio internal webserver goes to 500MB and i get a OutOfMemory Exception.

After a comment Child Page Code Behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        PopulateLatestClients()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateLatestClients()
    dpChTimeClient.DataSource = GetLatestClients()
    dpChTimeClient.DataTextField = "description"
    dpChTimeClient.DataValueField = "id"
    dpChTimeClient.DataBind()
    dpChTimeClient.Items.Insert(0, "")
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you setting the datasource for the ddl?

Answer (score 0):

It seem that GetLatestClients() return too much items. Have you checked that?

Comment: It's a select of TOP 25 records. Not to much data.